# Regex expression to exclude words surrounded by special characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I’ve been having issues with finding a solution to a regex conundrum I’m having.

Recently, I worked on a project where we needed to replace a list of words in a given text with a list of anchor tags.

For example, given a string

```
This is a test string
```

I may want to replace the word “test” with

```
<a target="_blank"  href="https://website.com/string-random“>test</a>.
```

The resulting string should look like this

```
This is a <a target="_blank" href="https://website.com/string-random“>test</a> string
```

The replacement of the words is done in a loop

```
foreach ($documents as $document)  
    foreach ($links as $link)
        replace keywords
```

What ends up happening in some scenarios is some of the urls in the anchor tags contain words that could potentially be replaced

For example, given this list of words to replace

```
[
    {
        'keyword': 'test',
        'link': 'https://website.com/string-random'
    },
    {
        'keyword': 'string',
        'link': 'https://random.com/string'
    }
]
```

After all the replacements are done, the sample string I gave above would look like this

```
This is a <a target="_blank" href="https://website.com/<a target="_blank"  href="https://random.com/string“>string</a>-random“>test</a> <a target="_blank" href="https://random.com/string“>string</a>
```

Instead of

```
This is a <a target="_blank" href="https://website.com/string-random“>test</a> <a target="_blank" href="https://random.com/string“>string</a>
```

Currently, I am looking for a regular expression that would not match on any words surrounded by special characters as I think this would solve my problem.

Also very open to any other ideas on how to tackle this problem

Answer (score 0):

This is not just about the previous replacements: any word that occurs within tag attributes / names / values is an issue.

In other words, you want to replace strings that are followed some chars where next < occurs before next > (strings between tags and not within tags)

Hence try this one :
`(string-to-match)(?=[^>]*?<)`

(replace string-to-match, obviously)

The other block is a lookahead : it ensures that you can read any char but >, as many times as needed, then a <

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
foreach ($wordlist as $word){
     $document = preg_replace("~(?! )($word[keyword])(?! )~i","<a href='$word[link]'>$1<")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a pattern that works pretty well for me hear
`$pattern = '/(?<!(>|\/|-))\b' . preg_quote($stringToReplace, '/') . '\b(?!(<|\/|-))/i';`